# Installed node.js and now vagrant doesn't work

Tags: node.js, vagrant

I've had a virtualbox working with vagrant on port 3000. The other day I installed node.js and now when I 'vagrant up' I get an error suggesting that port is already in use. Any change to my vagrantfile causes a change to be added to git. I don't want to change this file because other's share this repo. Can I change something on the node.js side so that it doesn't cause this issue?

When I try to see what's running on port 3000, I get this.

```
mapk$ lsof -i :3000
COMMAND    PID USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
VBoxHeadl 3527 mapk   18u  IPv4 0x5362d04fbb432fbf      0t0  TCP *:hbci (LISTEN)
```

Not sure if that helps.

Comment: Node can listen on pretty much any port. Set it to something you won't use for anything else.

Comment: @Shomz - thanks.  I figured as much, but my searches weren't giving me a clear way to do this. Is there a file I need to edit?

Comment: @mapk There is nothing built into Node.js that listens to connections all on its own.  Your application does that.  Chances are you are still running something in port 3000.  Simply modify your code to use something else.  Maybe in your case you have two VMs both trying to port forward to 3000?

Comment: It also could be defaulting to 3000, so if you search for number 3000 in your code, you won't find it. Show us how you setup your server.

Comment: I changed my app.js file to work with node on another port. This allowed my app.js file to start listening correctly. Thanks. However, vagrant still won't 'vagrant up'. This might be another question, but how to I kill everything on port 3000 restart this?

Comment: Ah yes, it retains the port for a while unless you exit properly... Try killing all node processes.